# How to constrain JavaFX Stage size to a square (width = height)?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I tried to implement what seemed to be an easy task at first, but I can't make it work.

I would like to force the main application window to be square.

The following snippet works when resizing the height of the window (it flickers, but the width is properly updated), but when I change the width of the stage it doesn't resize.

Does anyone know a better approach for constraining the stage size in javafx?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SquareStage extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Square Stage");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);

        ChangeListener<? super Number> listener = (ObservableValue<? extends Number> prop, Number oldVal, Number newVal) -> {
            if (prop == stage.widthProperty()) {
                stage.setHeight(newVal.doubleValue());
            }
            if (prop == stage.heightProperty()) {
                stage.setWidth(newVal.doubleValue());
            }
        };

        stage.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
        stage.heightProperty().addListener(listener);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use removeListener and addListener when changing value ​​to prevent listeners from chaining.

```java
private ChangeListener<? super Number> widthChangeListener;
private ChangeListener<? super Number> heightChangeListener;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    widthChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        primaryStage.heightProperty().removeListener(heightChangeListener);
        primaryStage.setHeight(newValue.doubleValue());
        primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener(heightChangeListener);
    };
    heightChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        primaryStage.widthProperty().removeListener(widthChangeListener);
        primaryStage.setWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
        primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener(widthChangeListener);
    };

    primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener(widthChangeListener);
    primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener(heightChangeListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) -> {
    stage.setHeight(t1.doubleValue());
});
stage.heightProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) -> {
    stage.setWidth(t1.doubleValue());
});
```

Comment: No, this is exaclty what I'm already doing. And is the same problem as rported by you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835898/javafx-stage-resizing-strange-behaviour

The problem remains - if I'm resizing height then it works, if I'm resizing width it doesn't (the width is reset to its original value)

Comment: I answered this before identifing the strange behavior. Sorry I didn't remove the answer.