# Maintain Gridpane the same height and width (Aspect ratio)

Tags: java, javafx, aspect-ratio

I have a javafx GridPane which which resizes itself to fit the dimensions of the Stage when I resize the stage. I want the height of the gridpane to match the width of the gridpane and thus resize to the maximum possible size maintaining this constraints.

I had to add more elements inside the parent of the GridPane. I found that the elements added were not behaving normally at all, and overlapping on top of each other.

Of course they stopped overlapping when I removed the overriding methods, but then again as I resize my stage the grid pane does not maintain a perfect square.

I thought of trying to use an image/imageView in the background and apply `setPreserveRatio(true)` for it. Then bind the heightProperty of this image to the gridPane's prefHeightProperty, but for some reason this is also not yeilding me any results.

Here is an MCVE of the second approach which is not working, but will be great if I can somehow make this work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        Image image = new Image("Square Image.png", 300, 300, true, true);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        // This makes the image resize while maintaining its square shape...
        imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty());
        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty());
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Pane pane = new Pane();
                pane.setPrefSize(100, 100);
                gridPane.add(pane, i, j);
            }
        }
        // Does not work as intended... :(
        gridPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(imageView.fitWidthProperty());
        gridPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(imageView.fitHeightProperty());
        
        /*
        Tried this as well, also does not work.. :(
        gridPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(image.widthProperty());
        gridPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(image.heightProperty());
        */


        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(imageView, gridPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Of course all of these approaches are cheap hacky methods of trying to get this done. If there is a standard way of doing it which I dont know then I would like to know that instead.

Comment: So you want to have your `GridPane` always maintain a perfect 1:1 square shape? If I understand correctly, just bind its width to its height: `gridPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(gridPane.prefHeightProperty());`

Comment: @zephyr You do not have bind() method available on read only properly like widthProperty() in GridPane. bind() can be only applied to prefWidthProperty(). And doing prefWidthProperty().bind(prefHeightProperty()) is also not working, just checked.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my comment. That will handle the `GridPane`, but you'll need to work out something similar if you want each of your squares to maintain their ratios as well.

Comment: I tried doing `gridPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(gridPane.prefHeightProperty());` but it is not working. I think since it is only setting the prefWidth and not the actual width, javafx is just ignoring this statement as it is not possible to fulfil such a demand like this

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish then. Do you want a fully scalable grid of boxes that maintain their proportions and always expand or shrink with the stage?

Comment: yes, exactly what I want, and the proportions that they should maintain is 1:1

Comment: Look into `ColumnConstraints` and `RowConstraints` as part of your `GridPane` and use an `AnchorPane` as its root.

Comment: Once you lock your `GridPane` into an `AnchorPane` that resizes with the `Stage`, you now need to handle cases where the stage itself is not resized in a 1:1 ratio. [This question/answer can help with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835504/how-to-constrain-javafx-stage-size-to-a-square-width-height)

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate the `GridPane` in a `StackPane` and use binding to dynamically change `GridPane` children preferred size while maintaining aspect ratio:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        private final int SIZE = 5;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
            gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            StackPane centerPane = new StackPane(gridPane);
            centerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:cyan");
            centerPane.setPrefSize(SIZE*50, SIZE*50);

            for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    Pane pane = new Pane();
                    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
                    gridPane.add(pane, i, j);
                    pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.min(centerPane.widthProperty().divide(SIZE),
                                                                centerPane.heightProperty().divide(SIZE)));
                    pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.min(centerPane.widthProperty().divide(SIZE),
                                                                centerPane.heightProperty().divide(SIZE)));
                }
            }
            gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(centerPane));
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: Problem is that this forces the cells of the `GridPane` to maintain a 1:1 ratio and so it appears that the `GridPane` is also maintaining the same ratio. But in reality, the `GridPane` is still extending the full size of the stage leaving its cells behind. This can be easily noticed if you set a background for the gridpane

Comment: What is the requirement ? Keep the `GripPane` square or its content  ? You can apply the binding to the `Gridpane` instead of its content. This will cause the content to remain at its preferred size.